# Passport for UK child born abroad

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, children

I am a British citizen by birth.  My wife is a Colombian national by birth and naturalized British. We have just had a child, born in Colombia, where we are currently residing.

If I understand correctly our child is considered to be British by descent.

I'm trying to figure out how best to get a passport for the child: should I do it in Britain when I am next there where, it appears, I just have to submit the numbers of my own and my wife's British passports, or do I need to do it from Colombia where, it appears, I need to submit both our birth certificates, our marriage certificate and a whole lot more.

Comment: How would your child get to the UK without a British passport?

Comment: @phoog: Perhaps with a Colombian passport? Sounds like the child is entitled to one, being a Colombian citizen.

Comment: I'll be back in Britain in a couple of months, by myself.  Child will be in Colombia with my wife.

Comment: How long will you be there?  Will you have an address where the passport will be delivered?  What happens if you have to return to Colombia before the passport is ready?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. The British passport can be applied for from Colombia or from the UK (if the child can get to the UK). Are you asking whether the child can enter the UK without a British passport?

Comment: Can I do it from the UK if I am there and the child is not?

Comment: You can do either. Depends on your circumstances and preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments here.

The answer is that you have to apply from where the child physically is.

The list of documents you have to send, according to the HMPO website and email service is extensive and complete overkill.  A *phone call* to HMPO will get personalised advice on what you actually need to send.  In my case I did NOT need to send physical passports, though was advised that colour photocopies "might help", which I did.

Application was turned around within a week without problems.